# How to specialize a call to generic function with specific derrivation of that generic in Java?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, polymorphism

I have a `Base` class and few of it's derived children, named `ChildN`.

Also i have a `Container` class, with `ChildN`-specific methods.

And finally i have a main class, where i wish to move all `Base`-generic logic into helper method, but somewhere in middle of this logic i may have need to put a `ChildN`-specific object into correct method of `Container` class. How do i do that? How to specialize a call to `hassleSafeAdder` with correct `ChildN` type, so it be accessible in this method and i could cast to it, or do some other thing which enable correct dispatching of object to right method?

```
// base class
public static class Base { }

// derived classes
public static class Child1 extends Base { }
public static class Child2 extends Base { }
public static class Child3 extends Base { }
public static class Child4 extends Base { }

// class with derived types in method signature
public static class Container {
    public void add(Child1 obj) { }
    public void add(Child2 obj) { }
    public void add(Child3 obj) { }
    public void add(Child4 obj) { }
}

// main class where execution happens
public static class Main {
    private static <T extends Base> void hassleSafeAdder(Container container, T value) {
        // do some hassle
        container.add(value); // error, because T could be any Base derivation, while container has only ChildN-specific ones.
        // cleanup hassle resources
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container container = new Container();

        // how to parametrize this calls so they will be valid?
        hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child1());
        hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child2());
        hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child3());
        hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child4());
    }
}
```

Desired pseudo-code:

```
        hassleSafeAdder<Child1>(container, new Child1());
        hassleSafeAdder<Child2>(container, new Child2());
        hassleSafeAdder<Child3>(container, new Child3());
        hassleSafeAdder<Child4>(container, new Child4());
```

Comment: Why the overloaded methods? Why not just one add(Base)?

Comment: This is an oversimplified example, in real thing they do different logic, so adding `Child1` and `Child2` is not similar and require that specific `ChildN` actions for the `Container`.

Comment: `hassleSafeAdder`'s signature should just be `private static void hassleSafeAdder(Container container, Base value)`. The `T` is pointless

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) pattern.

```
class Ideone
{
private static <T extends Base> void hassleSafeAdder(Container container, T value) {
        value.addToContainer(container);
    }

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Container container = new Container();

    hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child1());
    hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child2());
    hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child3());
    hassleSafeAdder(container, new Child4());

}

public static class Container {
    public void add(Child1 obj) { }
    public void add(Child2 obj) { }
    public void add(Child3 obj) { }
    public void add(Child4 obj) { }
}

public static abstract class Base { 

    public abstract void addToContainer(Container container);

}

public static class Child1 extends Base {

    public void addToContainer(Container container) {
        container.add(this);    
    }
}

public static class Child2 extends Base {

    public void addToContainer(Container container) {
        container.add(this);    
    }
}

public static class Child3 extends Base {

    public void addToContainer(Container container) {
        container.add(this);    
    }
}

public static class Child4 extends Base {

    public void addToContainer(Container container) {
        container.add(this);    
    }
}
}
```